# Add XAML element from another class

Tags: c#, class, xaml

I want to add a TextBlock to a StackPanel in the MainWindow from another class. If I just try to create a new TextBlock element inside the class, I get the error that it must be an STA Thread. Then I tried to add `[STAThread]` over the method, but it doesn't do anything. After that I tried to create a new thread, but then I get the error, that the element I try to add the TextBlock as a child is in a different thread.

Now my question is, how do I add a new xaml element in the MainWindow.xaml from another classes event?

MainWindow.xaml.cs code: https://pastebin.com/3mFUZhaZ

MainWindow.xaml code: https://pastebin.com/D1RqsUkS

Bot.cs code: https://pastebin.com/pzRuVE2D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code. What are you actually trying to achieve? Chances are, Threads are the wrong approach here.

Comment: You should not add controls manually. Better use `DataBinding` with `MVVM` pattern. This is the way WPF should be used.

Comment: I edited my Post, that are my MainWindow.xaml.cs, MainWindow.xaml and Bot.cs classes, I cleaned up the code a little bit, so it's not too long. But that's the code snippets where my problem occur.

Comment: But I can't add new elements to a StackPanel using DataBinding, or do I? By the way, I want to create a Chat Window, and the TextBlock should be the single chat messages :)

Comment: You cannot add them to a StackPanel but you can use an `ItemsControl` instead of the stackPanel. You only need to set the `ItemTemplate` to tell the control it should add a TextBlock for each item in its ItemsSource

Comment: ... or, if you don't need the flexibility of `ItemsControl`, use a `ListView`

Comment: I tried it using a ListView and adding a text like so: ``mw.ChatWindow.Items.Add("TEST");`` but then I get an error, that it can't be accessed because it's in another thread. :/

Comment: Now I tried it using a ItemsControl element too and used the same command to add text to it, but it doesn't work neither

Comment: You may not use Items.Add on the control, when you use DataBinding. Bind the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection in your ViewModel, or your CodeBehind file, if you do not use MVVM and add elements to this collection. If you do this in another thread, you have to use a Dispatcher